# keep getting syntax error in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a certificate and now I want to remove certificate signature and drop the certificate. When I supply the certificate name directly it is working but when I'm making use of local variables to supply the name its giving me syntax error.

I have tried with different datatypes as well

```
text, varbinary(max), char(200), varchar(200), nvarchar(200)
```

None of these datatypes are working.

```
declare @certificate nvarchar(200) 
set @certificate = 'ITManagerCertificate'

begin transaction
use DBwork

-- remove signature from stored procedure
drop signature from Report_Manager
by certificate @certificate

-- drop certificate
--DROP CERTIFICATE @certificate 

if @@ERROR > 0
begin 
   rollback transaction
end 
else begin
   commit transaction
end
```

Comment: I don't think you can parameterize that; you'll need to use dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: You need to learn how to read the syntax diagrams in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186977.aspx). For `certificate`, it says `CERTIFICATE cert_name` which means it needs a literal name there - not a *string*, not a *variable*. If you're allowed such things, they're explicitly indicated. E.g. if a variable was allowed, it would instead have `CERTIFICATE cert_name | @cert_name_variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @certificate nvarchar(200)
declare @sql nvarchar(1000) 
set @certificate = N'ITManagerCertificate'

begin transaction
use DBwork
--Remove Signature from Store procedure
set @sql= N'drop signature from Report_Manager
by certificate '+ @certificate
execute sp_executesql @sql
--Drop certificate
--DROP CERTIFICATE @certificate 

if @@ERROR > 0
begin 
rollback transaction
end 
else begin
commit transaction
end
```